# AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7

I am trying to run the below program using asyncio:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('World')

asyncio.run(main())
```

However, I am getting the following error:

**AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'**

*python --version gives: Python 2.7.8*

*python3 --version gives: Python 3.7.1*

I am running the script as **python3 script.py**

Any ideas on how can I run this program without any error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My bet: your `script.py` file actually has name `asyncio.py` (or you have such file somewhere in `PYTHONPATH`). Rename it to something different and everything will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had another file called asyncio.py lying in my machine.

Comment: @Mihika you're welcome. I think there's no Python developer on a planet who didn't face or won't face this situation :)

Comment: guess what was the name of my python file .... shame on me ... thanks Mihika

Comment: I'm new to python and I was naming the file asyncio.py 

Comment: I did named asynciol.py, you saved my day!!

Answer (score 2):

I am late to the party, but I faced the same issue while trying to run a fastapi program onto Azure App Services.

I could not find any `asyncio.py` onto my system, as suggested by @Mikhail Gerasimov, but the fix described [here](https://programmerah.com/python3-6-run-uvicorn-error-attributeerror-module-asyncio-has-no-attribute-run-49450/) did the trick:

```
pip uninstall uvicorn
pip install uvicorn==0.16.0
```